# form.submit() will trigger double inside a form

Tags: java, jquery, forms, jsp, post

Good day,

The following is my jsp code:

```
<s:form beanclass="c.c.i.c.app.profile.ui.ChangePasswordAction" method="post" name="form1">
<!-- some others code here -->
     <sx:row cssClass="button_row">
          <sx:input name="updatePassword" image="submit"/>  
     </sx:row>
</s:form>
```

And this is my `jquery`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(':input[name=updatePassword]').click(function() {

        var answerProceed = confirm("Do you wish to proceed with the changes?");

        if( answerProceed ){
            var form = $("form[name=form1]");
            form.attr("action", '<s:url beanclass="c.c.i.c.app.profile.ui.ChangePasswordAction" event="update"/>');
            form.submit();
        } else {
        return false;}
    });
</script>
```

We can see that, in the jQuery, it will trigger a `update` event to `ChangePasswordAction`.

However, currently I have a issue, which is sometimes it will trigger 2 times, its not always happen, but the happen rate is about 50%.

The following is the trigger log I get from my application log:

```
2019-06-26 18:19:13.658 [WebContainer : 31] TRACE o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - [bmaker] - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.event.authorization.AuthorizedEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /common/change_password.html?update=&__stoken=1a47d3a9-29e8-4904-b204-3cb9fc0129f0]
2019-06-26 18:19:13.660 [WebContainer : 26] TRACE o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext - [bmaker] - Publishing event in Root WebApplicationContext: org.springframework.security.event.authorization.AuthorizedEvent[source=FilterInvocation: URL: /common/change_password.html?update=&__stoken=1a47d3a9-29e8-4904-b204-3cb9fc0129f0]
```

Anyone know what wrong with the code?

Comment: If input is of type submit in your form you must `preventDefault()` in your javascript if you want to check for confirmation before submitting the form. i.e. : `...click(function() { e.preventDefault(); var answerProceed...` where `e` is implicit `Event` implementation parameter like `MouseEvent` in your case.

Comment: Hi @Paul, sorry for late reply, you can update as answer and I will mark it as my correct answer.

Comment: All right, I wrote the answer. I'll delete my comments once the answer will be accepted.

Comment: @Paul , Is OK, you can leave the comment here, its useful also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an `<input/>` is of `type="submit"` in a form you have to use `preventDefault()` if you want to check for confirmation before you submit the form. 
You can pass `e` as parameter in your listener as an `Event` implementation parameter like `MouseEvent` (because of the *click* event) in this case.

For example :

```
$(':input[name=updatePassword]').click(function(e) { // <-- e implements Event
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent the submit of the form
    var answerProceed = confirm("Do you wish to proceed with the changes?");
    if (answerProceed) {
        var form = $("form[name=form1]");
        // var form = e.currentTarget.form; you can do this
        // var form = this.form; or you can do this, "this" is implicit clicked element
        form.attr("action", '<s:url beanclass="c.c.i.c.app.profile.ui.ChangePasswordAction" event="update"/>');
        form.submit();
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

You can access the form of an element by doing `.form` on an element, see 
[HTMLSelectElement.form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/form)

**See**

[Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

[Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event)

[MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)